# Sending a keypress to an application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

Is there an easy way to make an application think the user has pressed a key?

Here's why I am trying to do this:

I am trying to track down a regression in a Wine application.  The bug only seems to show itself when the user presses a specific key (in this case, escape).  So I wanted to give `git bisect` a script that launches the application, simulates pressing escape, and tells git that that the revision is bad if the program crashes.

Comment: What language is the script in?

Comment: @Wooble I haven't written it yet, so I'm not particularly concerned with which language to use.  I guess, whichever language it is easiest to do this in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xdotool: http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

Answer (score 0):

There is some sample code at: http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html

It might be roughly what you need. Also read the comments (there is a sample for selecting a window in a different way).