# How to simulate keyboard input to a console application?

Tags: bash, testing, automated-tests

I have developed an application in bash that uses "whiptail" to display dialogs in a terminal.
(I personnally don't like this kind of UI but i'm only a developer, i don't make decisions ...). Anyway, now i have to test it, and i would like to simulate a user that types values, press "Enter", "Echap", "Tab", "down arrow", "up arrow"

I didn't get *expect* working and it seems it is not possible (http://oldsite.debianhelp.org/node/11812).

Edit: There is no X on the machine, so xdotool is not suitable. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't need to install anything (because we are not allowed to add programs to the system to test it).

Long story made short, i'm looking for a solution like "writing bytes to the process's stdin" or "writing on the keyboard device in /dev", something like that.

Thanks

Comment: You can do it with xdotool. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312527/sending-a-keypress-to-an-application/7312865#7312865

Comment: There is no X on the system, its only a console application

Comment: [Here's one method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370538/ask-a-running-bash-interactive-to-run-a-command-from-outside/7370822#7370822)

Comment: You are a life saver ! You found the answer i was looking for, can you make a true "answer" so that i can accept it ? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pass in an input file like

```
 $ yourscript.sh < inputfile
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work:
root@antec# echo "user input here" > /tmp/test; whiptail --inputbox "test" 20 50 < /tmp/test

Answer (score 1):

Your Bash application requires a [pseudo terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) in order to run properly. It needs a screen size and a cursor position, but if you run it with piped input (`<` or `|`), no pseudo terminal gets created.

Pseudo terminals get created in Unix by everyday applications like `ssh`, `xterm`, and `screen`. ([Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) will create a pseudo terminal for your application and allow you to run automated tests. It supports test generation with [`autoexpect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/autoexpect.man.html), and there is a paper on [using Expect for terminal screen-scraping](http://expect.sourceforge.net/doc/chargraph.pdf).)

If you can't use Expect, you can try using `screen` for automated terminal I/O:

```
# Create a detached screen
screen -S screenname -d -m -s ./my_app

# Send input to it
screen -S screenname -p windownum -X eval \
  "register . \"arbitrary\ntext, newlines and control chars\n\"" paste

# Wait for the application to process the input
sleep 0.1s

# Dump the screen to a file
screen -S screenname -p windownum -X hardcopy ./screen_dump

# Check the dump
grep 'Login successful' ./screen_dump || exit 1

# Rinse and repeat

# Close the screen
screen -S screenname -X quit
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "paste ." instead of just paste?